# How do I get to choose MAX value by result of column?

Tags: sql

I have this simple Table about chat Item

[image]

I have my query that gets latest entered chat by chatId item as follow

```
  select MAX(id)
  from ChatItem
  WHERE ChatItem.CaseInvoiceId = 160670
```

Now I would like to get latest item with isDone = 0 as priority.

If any of result row has isDone = 0, it will get MAX(ID) with isDone = 0.
If not, it will get the MAX(ID) with isDone = 1.

Is there any simple and beautiful way to make this?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
select top 1 id
from ChatItem
where ChatItem.CaseInvoiceId = 160670
order by isdone, id desc
```

The idea is to order it by `isDone` in `ASC` order so 0 should be first (if there is any) and then order it by id in `DESC` order so MAX value should be on top and then return the top row.

This was written and tested on SQL Server.

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell the rest of us which dbms this is for.

Comment: @jarlh to me it looks like SQL Server management Studio. And I believe there is nothing product specific!? Basic SQL query. Almost the same as the user used just added `ORDER BY` clause. Don't think it should break something.

Comment: `top 1` is a MS SQL special. ANSI SQL has FETCH FIRST instead. (Which MS SQL has now too.)

Comment: Okey. I believe that is a minor problem. User could adapt it to his dbms. The main idea was to order it properly and then just return the first row. He could use `LIMIT 1`, `TOP 1` or `FETCH FIRST`

Comment: For you and me it's a minor problem, but there are lots of beginners here too.

Comment: Great! How come I've never thought of this

Answer (score 0):

Just add your condition with an `and`:

```
select max ("Id")
from "ChatItem"
where "CaseInvoiceId" = 160670 and "isDone" = 0;
```

Example:

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/be7ujQ4zMzzYaDS8Tg5d4v/0